# small / little poodle & bark at all / bark at everything & It’s / That’s my mom’s dog

Tags: phrase-usage

As I understand, there are interchangeable these sentences, aren't they?

> I have a small poodle. / **I have a little poodle.**

> They bark at all. / **They bark at everything.**

> **It’s my mom’s dog.** / That’s my mom’s dog.

P.S. Some phrases were taken from one English dialogue. (in Bold)

Comment: "They bark at all," is not idiomatic. The phrase "at all" has a fixed meaning of "even slightly" (it does not mean "at everything").  It is used as an intensifier in negative sentences.  For example, "They **don't** bark **at all**," means that they don't bark even in the slightest amount.

Comment: Can I say: "Our dog doesn’t bark at everything."?

Comment: Yes.  That means that he barks at some things, but not all things.  If you wanted to say that the dog never barks at things, you could say "Our dog doesn't bark at anything."

Comment: So, "Our dog doesn't bark at anything." and "Our dog doesn’t bark at all." are the same in this context?

Comment: "Our dog doesn't bark at anything" leaves open the possibility that the dog sometimes barks "at nothing" - that is for no reason and directed at no thing, but this would be a weird way of expressing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Not quite

> - I have a small poodle.
> - I have a little poodle.

These two are essential identical in meaning, although "little " is perhaps a stronger statement. In other contexts "I have a little X" can mean "I have a small amount of X" but not here.

> - <s>They bark at all.</s>

> - They bark at everything.

"They bark at all": is simply not a valid sentence, and has no meaning. The similar sounding "They don't bark at all." means "They never bark." while "They bark at all people." means that they bark at each person.

> - It’s my mom’s dog.
> - That’s my mom’s dog.

Both of the above are valid, but the usage is different. "That’s my mom’s dog." would more often be used when pointing at or otherwise indicating the specific dog. The phrase " It’s my mom’s dog." would most often be used when the dog has been mentioned in a previous sentence in the same passage. For example:

> I don't feed the dog.  It’s my mom’s dog. She feeds it.

Comment: Can I say: "Our dog doesn’t bark at everything."?

Comment: Only Collins dictionary says that "You use "that" to refer back to an idea or situation expressed in a previous sentence or sentences."

Comment: @Sergey You can say "Our dog doesn’t bark at everything." but it likely means "Our dog only barks at some things" not "our dog never barks". "That" can be used in quite a few different ways, but in this sort of construction, I think the ways i described are by far the most common.